# Cell formatting with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add 0.00 if the cell value is not empty and not 0.Below code i am trying but not working:

```
 For x = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count Step 1
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(x).Range("A1:Z30")
      Set FinColumn = .Find(What:="price", AFter:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
          :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
          False, SearchFormat:=False)
      If FinColumn Is Nothing Then
      Else
        I = FinColumn.Row + 1
        c = FinColumn.Column
    **problem with below Do loop,no clues how to do**
        **Do Until .Cells(I, c).Value <> "" And .Cells(I, c).Value <> 0
          .Cells(I, c).NumberFormat = "0.00"
          I = I + 1
        Loop**
      End If
    End With
  Next x
```

Please provide code to meet below conditions:
 I want the code to work in both prior versions of 2007 also and must meet below conditions:

if the data is like below in excel:

```
Emp Name  Emp id  Empsal

Jhon      1        

steve     2        2

mike      3        3.5

paul      4        0

gabriel   5        0.00

bush      6        null
```

if i run the macro ,data should be converted to below format in Empsal column:

```
Emp Name  Emp id  Empsal

Jhon      1        0

steve     2        2

mike      3        3.50

paul      4        0

gabriel    5       0.00

bush       6      0
```

Thanks,

Chaitu

Comment: Aren't you setting non zero non blank cells to = 0.00 instead of appending .00?

Comment: Not telling what the problem/error is greatly reduces the chance you'll get an answer.

Comment: I wanted to be append .00 only when cell is not blank and not zero.if it is 0 or null leave it as 0

Answer (score 5):

i recommend using custom number format without using VBA, e.g.:

```
[=0]0;0.00
```

or if you want nice big numbers too:

```
[=0]0;[>=1000]# ### ###;0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

**TRIED AND TESTED (FASTEST METHOD)**

This code uses Conditional Formatting. The only drawback is that this code will work in Excel 2007 onwards :P So if you have Excel 2003 then this will not work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim FinColumn As Range

    For x = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(x).Range("A1:Z30")
            Set FinColumn = .Find(What:="price", AFter:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not FinColumn Is Nothing Then
                With Worksheets(x).Columns(FinColumn.Column)
                    .NumberFormat = "General"
                    .FormatConditions.Delete
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
                    Formula1:="=0"
                    .FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = "0.00"
                    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: I want the code to work in both prior versions of 2007 also and must meet below conditions:  1 )if cell value is null or empty show 0,

2) if cell value is 1 show 1

3)if cell value is 1.29 show 1.29

4)if cell value is 0 then show 0

Comment: Could you please check this one.i updated my question

Comment: You data for paul and gabriel is same so why different formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I take it you mean you want `"0.00"` entered as a numeric value but formatted to look like "0.00"?  In which case...

```
.Cells(I, c).Value = 0
.Cells(I, c).NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

Comment: I wanted to be append .00 only when cell is not blank and not zero.if it is 0 or null leave it as 0

Comment: Perhaps you should specify what result your currently getting, because I fail to see how your original code would return anything other than what you asked for (whether it "0.00" or ".00")?

Comment: I am getting 0.00 if the value is 0 or blank or null.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop:

```
     Do Until .Cells(I, c).Value <> "" And .Cells(I, c).Value <> 0
      .Cells(I, c).Value = "0.00"
      I = I + 1
    Loop
```

Is looping until it finds a non-null/non-zero value, and it unconditionally sets every null cell to 0 here:

```
.Cells(I, c).Value = "0.00"
```

(With general formating on a fresh worksheet, this value would appear as 0, not 0.00, unless you are either resusing a worksheet or changed your default formatting).

If you meant to only set non-null values, you need to change loop's limit condition doesn't conflict with the secondary non-null/null cell test.
Within that loop ( that's search for non-null), do something independently to check each cell for non-null or not. (like a if/then/else to set its value).

Comment: Loops are too expensive for this time wise, much better to use the `Find` approch that the question contains

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I know what you mean now.  The problem is that you've entered an impossible `Do Until` Statement, because you cell value could never be Blank `AND` 0 at the same time, so your likely getting an infinite loop

Below, I've simply replaced your `AND` with `OR`

```
Do Until .Cells(I, c).Value <> "" Or .Cells(I, c).Value <> 0
  .Cells(I, c).Value = "0.00"
  I = I + 1
Loop
```

Or, if that still doesn't cover it, then try using `<> Empty`, because `Empty` would cover both 0 and ""

```
Do Until .Cells(I, c).Value <> Empty
  .Cells(I, c).Value = "0.00"
  I = I + 1
Loop
```

Comment: I have to perform below cases to existing code:1 )if cell value is null or empty show 0, 
2) if cell value is 1 show 1
3)if cell value is 1.29 show 1.29 
4)if cell value is 0 then show 0

Comment: Surely your original code plus the above edit will achieve your stated cases? If I'm wrong, please clarify where your issue lies.  From what I see cases 2-3 are the same, and are achieved through processing of case 1, which you've already done?  If I was to start some guesswork I'd say what you actually mean is that you don't what your loop to stop at the first empty cell, but to continue just without edit those cells.  But this is no place for guesswork, you need make your question clearer.

Comment: How the case 2 and 3 are same .If the input cell value is not having any decimals.i have to keep like that,if it has decimals ,i have to set Number format to 0.00,apart from this if the cell value is null ,empty or 0 i have to show 0. I dont have nay clue how to dhat.if you got any idea,please give me the answer.

Comment: They are the same in the sense that there is nothing to change, eg. 1 is already 1, 1.29 is already 1.29 0 is already 0 (note I meant to say 2-4 above).  Case 1 is the only case which requires a change, so surely it's the only one you need to focus on?

Comment: Skytunnel: I dont understand why your not understanding my question.in what aspect you dont understand the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've already explained why your question isn't clear.  But if you have already given all the detail you have on the question then someone should be able to answer.  But I will have to take a step back from here

Comment: Looks like may be my mistake,i provided example data.please have a look.thanks in advance.